# Write some text in input field and capture <Enter> button press and then display it in bootstrap card using array and current time

Tags: typescript, angular6

[image: Added the image for your reference]Here is my html file where i have hardcoded some message I need to populate the card when the user presses  after writing in the input field.The input field is outside the bootstrap card and i have to populate the information typed by the user inside the card. Please help me guys and I have to also print the current time.

```
<div class="conversation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header cardContainer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <div aria-controls="caseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#messages" class="basicData active">
                                    <div class="name font-corpos">Messages</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <div aria-controls="caseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#attachments"
                                    class="basicData">
                                    <div class="name font-corpos">Attachments</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 team">
                        <img src="assets/images/conversation/Team.svg" alt="group">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body cardbodyContainer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <span class="conversationsText font-corpos">Conversations</span>
                        <span class="activeParticipantsText font-corpos">4 active participants</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 more">
                        <app-more-menu></app-more-menu>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="style-two">
                <div class="messageReceiver">
                    <div class="receiverName font-corpos">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                    </div>
                    <div class="receiverMessage font-corpos">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                    </div>
                    <hr class="receiverHorizontalLine">
                    <div class="attachment">
                        <img src="assets/images/conversation/Attachment(1).svg" alt="attachment">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeReceiver">
                    10:32 PM
                </div>
                <div class="messageSender">
                    <div class="senderMessage">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeSender">
                    10.45 PM
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input id="icon" type="text" class="inputField" placeholder="Type message here...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ts file goes like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conversation',
  templateUrl: './conversation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conversation.component.scss']
})
export class ConversationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Any help is honestly appreciated since Im new to angular 6. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for easy way, please look changes and try it, this solution will help you.

Your Html Code.

```
<div class="conversation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header cardContainer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <div aria-controls="caseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#messages" class="basicData active">
                                        <div class="name font-corpos">Messages</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <div aria-controls="caseTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#attachments"
                                        class="basicData">
                                        <div class="name font-corpos">Attachments</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 team">
                            <img src="assets/images/conversation/Team.svg" alt="group">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body cardbodyContainer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <span class="conversationsText font-corpos">Conversations</span>
                            <span class="activeParticipantsText font-corpos">4 active participants</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 more">
                            <app-more-menu></app-more-menu>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="style-two">
                    <div class="messageReceiver">
                        <div class="receiverName font-corpos">
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </div>
                        <div class="receiverMessage font-corpos">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                            the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                            of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                        </div>
                        <hr class="receiverHorizontalLine">
                        <div class="attachment">
                            <img src="assets/images/conversation/Attachment(1).svg" alt="attachment">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeReceiver">
                        10:32 PM
                    </div>
                <div *ngFor="let message of senderMessages">
                    <div class="messageSender">
                        <div class="senderMessage">
                               {{message.senderMessage}} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeSender">
                        {{message.senderTime}}
                    </div>
               </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <input id="icon" type="text" class="inputField" placeholder="Type message here..." (keyup.enter)="inputEnterBtnEvent($event)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your ts file .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conversation',
  templateUrl: './conversation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conversation.component.scss']
})
export class ConversationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private datePipe:DatePipe) { }
senderMessages:any = [{senderMessage:"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",senderTime:"10.45 PM"}];//Your HardCoded Message.

  ngOnInit() {

  }

inputEnterBtnEvent(evnt){
this.senderMessages.push({senderMessage:evnt.currentTarget.value,senderTime:this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),'h:mm a')});

}

}
```

Note:- please mention "DatePipe" in app module providers(app.module.ts--> providers) otherwise you wil get errors on date pipe using.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.. but i have to populate the container not with one message but with many so i have to make use of an empty array initially and the push the new data coming from the input field

Comment: yes that is the thing only i am doing in .ts file, please find array push in .ts file. i given your hard coded message initial array for display, 
========>
inputEnterBtnEvent(evnt){
this.senderMessages.push({senderMessage:evnt.currentTarget.value,senderTime:this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),'h:mm a')});

}

Comment: If I click "Enter" button without the letter being typed in the input field. Please help me to remove this bug.

Comment: Check condition enter text is empty or not,
check this code
------------->
inputEnterBtnEvent(evnt){
      let enteredText = evnt.currentTarget.value;
      if(enteredText.length > 0){
        this.senderMessages.push({senderMessage:enteredText,senderTime:this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),'h:mm a')});
      }
      
      
      }
<-------------